# Controlling two Nokia 5110 screens to show identical things over SPI (Arduino)

Tags: arduino, screen, nokia, spi, lcd

I'm working on a project which requires two Nokia 5110 screens, but they are always displaying exactly the same things.

Since I do not have to send different information to each screen, can I run them both off the same SPI lines (including Chip Select)? I would prefer to do away with treating each screen individually, and hence having two Chip Selects.

Nic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your SPI link is one way (i.e., only using SCLK, MOSI, and SS and specifically *not* using MISO) then you could just connect both displays to the same SPI connection, and you should get identical display on both. The host won't know that two displays are listenting, and each display will not know that another is listening to the same data. They should both respond to your commands and display the same thing.

If you *are* using MISO then you could just connect that to one display (since the other would be returning the same data anyway).